# Enable to instal Magenta on WinPython 3.11

Tags: magenta

I am encountering issue to install Magenta with my WinPython 3.11 installed on my external drive.

I have installed Microsoft Visual C++ Build Tools: specifically Desktop development with C++ only and Cython. I tried then to install Magenta and I got the following errors:

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [39 lines of output]
C:\Users\Massimiliano\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tj5nh9jk\python-rtmidi_c7a754bbdaa64e6faea45e3147fbce6c\setup.py:25: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
JACK1_MIN_VERSION = StrictVersion('0.125.0')
C:\Users\Massimiliano\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tj5nh9jk\python-rtmidi_c7a754bbdaa64e6faea45e3147fbce6c\setup.py:26: DeprecationWarning: distutils Version classes are deprecated. Use packaging.version instead.
JACK2_MIN_VERSION = StrictVersion('1.9.11')
performance hint: src_rtmidi.pyx:211:5: Exception check on '_cb_func' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
1. Declare '_cb_func' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
2. Use an 'int' return type on '_cb_func' to allow an error code to be returned.
performance hint: src_rtmidi.pyx:219:5: Exception check on '_cb_error_func' will always require the GIL to be acquired.
Possible solutions:
1. Declare '_cb_error_func' as 'noexcept' if you control the definition and you're sure you don't want the function to raise exceptions.
2. Use an 'int' return type on '_cb_error_func' to allow an error code to be returned.

```
  Error compiling Cython file:
  ------------------------------------------------------------
  ...
          """
          if self._callback:
              self.cancel_callback()

          self._callback = (func, data)
          self.thisptr.setCallback(&_cb_func, <void *>self._callback)
                                   ^
  ------------------------------------------------------------

  src\_rtmidi.pyx:941:33: Cannot assign type 'void (*)(double, vector[unsigned char] *, void *) except * nogil' to 'RtMidiCallback'. Exception values are incompatible. Suggest adding 'noexcept' to type 'void (double, vector[unsigned char] *, void *) except * nogil'.
  Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
    File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
    File "C:\Users\Massimiliano\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-tj5nh9jk\python-rtmidi_c7a754bbdaa64e6faea45e3147fbce6c\setup.py", line 191, in <module>
      ext_modules=cythonize(extensions),
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    File "E:\Python\WPy64-31160\python-3.11.6.amd64\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1154, in cythonize
      cythonize_one(*args)
    File "E:\Python\WPy64-31160\python-3.11.6.amd64\Lib\site-packages\Cython\Build\Dependencies.py", line 1321, in cythonize_one
      raise CompileError(None, pyx_file)
  Cython.Compiler.Errors.CompileError: src\_rtmidi.pyx
  Compiling src\_rtmidi.pyx because it changed.
  [1/1] Cythonizing src\_rtmidi.pyx
  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.

I have upgraded Cython, installed the dependencies separately, I have installed wheels and tensorflow but when I went to install Magenta, I always got the same type of error - compilation and conflict issues with the python-rtmidi package.

I have a HP Probook with the following:
Processor   Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-8550U CPU @ 1.80GHz   1.99 GHz
Installed RAM   16.0 GB (15.9 GB usable)

Would anyone be so kind as to advice what I should do to resolve the issue and install Magenta?
Thank you so much in advance.